# Adding a value to a previous value with for loop

Tags: r, loops

I'm starting with a value, say 10 and then want to add a number to it (from a matrix/vector), once getting this result, I want to add the next number in the matrix to this result and so on.

```
 numbers <- c(1:10)
 matrix2 <- matrix("", 1,11)
 matrix2 <- as.numeric(matrix2)

aggregate <-  for (i in length(matrix2 +1)) {
         matrix2[1] <- 10
         matrix2[1+i] <- matrix2[1] + numbers[i]
    }
```

For this I get a result of NULL

What I was expecting was:

```
       10
 10+1 = 11
 11+2 = 13
 13+3 = 16
 16+4 = 20
 20+5 = 25
```

So after each iteration, the previous result would have the next number in the "numbers" vector added to it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not do `10 + cumsum(numbers)`?

Comment: Works great! Although i was a little confused why my loop doesnt work...

Comment: You might consider checking in matrix2, as that's where you assign numbers inside your loop.... But generally, for-loops are not the way to go in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numbers <- c(1:10)
matrix2 <- matrix("", 1,11)
matrix2 <- as.numeric(matrix2)

matrix2[1] <- 10
for (i in 2:length(matrix2 +1)) {
  matrix2[i] <- matrix2[i-1] + numbers[i-1]
}
```

You need to give the for loop a start and an end point, and the way you had indexed the vector was not going to give you the result you had indicated.

Comment: Thanks for the pick up!